# How to use initializer list to initialize std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++17

The non-variant version of initializer list works good:

```
std::map<int, double> a = {{1,0.1}};
```

But the variant version doesn't:

```
std::variant<std::map<int, double>, int> b = {{1,0.1}};
```

Is there a way to initialize b using initializer list? If not, what is the best way to initialize it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to be more specific:

```
std::variant<std::map<int, double>, int> b = std::map<int, double>{{1,0.1}};
```

Not ideal, but the compiler cannot choose the right overload of `std::variant` constructor from a `<brace-enclosed initializer list>`. Because of how the relevant [`std::variant` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) is defined:

```
template< class T >
constexpr variant( T&& t ) noexcept(/* see below */);
```

`T&& t` cannot possibly match a `<brace-enclosed initializer list>`, only a value of a specific type.